# Why is Sega Saturn mysteriously missing from No-Intros.org's hash database?

Tags: rom, game-consoles, sega

https://datomatic.no-intro.org/index.php?page=download

This website has the *worst*, most cryptic and broken interface I've ever seen in my life, but eventually, I managed to download a big archive containing .dat files (which are actually some kind of XML files) containing every single video game title and the hashes for their files/ROMs, used to verify your own collection to make sure they have not been modified or incorrectly captured.

For example:

```
Sega - Master System - Mark III (Parent-Clone) (20200429-062328).dat
Sega - Mega Drive - Genesis (Parent-Clone) (20200822-054519).dat
...
```

There's also one for PlayStation, and for every other console ever, basically. But not one for Saturn. That's the one console I see missing. Many way more obscure ones are included, but not Sega Saturn.

What could possibly explain this?

I would refuse to use the website out of principle, just because I can't stand cryptic/idiotic interfaces, but this data is simply not available anywhere else online. (Or, if it is, it is extremely well hidden.)

I also don't understand what the "(Parent-Clone)" parts mean.

Comment: Have you tried to contact the website either through the discussion board or the contact email address on the linked page? They can probably answer the question much better than most people here.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because there's an alternative preservation hashing project named *Redump* that focuses on optical media. Since No-Intro focuses on cartridge games, it would be duplicated (though not wasted) effort for both projects to spend time on the Saturn.

On No-Intro's website:

> Welcome to the No-Intro wiki!
>
> We specialize in video game preservation for **cartridge based systems** (my emphases) listed here.

From [Pleasuredome](http://wiki.pleasuredome.org.uk/index.php/Comparison_of_ROMs_sets#Redump)'s directory of these kinds of projects:

> **Redump**
>
> Similiar mission as No-Intro but **only for optical media**, also not quite as pure as Trurip: Redump.org is a disc preservation database and internet community dedicated to collecting precise and accurate information about every video game ever released on optical media of any system. The goal is to make blueprints of the data on console and PC game discs.

In [this github post](http://robloach.github.io/awesome-dats/dats.xml), you can see a list of dats for more systems, and how they interleave both No-Intro and Redump dats to cover more systems.